# How to find the difference between event dates in the time line using php?

Tags: php

Actually I am working on the 2002 ( old php project) based on the requirement. So my work is to show the difference between events markers based on the dates by placing some width dynamically in php. So I wrote the code after that it is not even displaying the events markers in the page.

I will provide the code which I wrote for this requirement.

```
    function getEvents($uid)
{

$timeLineQry = mysql_query("select * from timelines where user_id = $uid and status=1 order by id desc");

    if(mysql_num_rows($timeLineQry) > 0)
    {
        $data='';
        while($tres = mysql_fetch_assoc($timeLineQry))
        {


            $data.='<div class="events-chat" id="timeline'.$tres['id'].'">
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="addEvent('.$tres['id'].')"> Add Event</button>
<div id="" style="float:right;">
<span style="margin-left: 10px;color: #696767;
cursor: pointer;margin-right: 25px;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: inherit;" onclick="getTimeLine(\''.$tres['title'].'\',\''.$tres['description'].'\',\''.$tres['id'].'\')">'.$tres['title'].'</span>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="deleteTimeline('.$tres['id'].')"></i>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;margin-bottom:35px;"></div>
<div id="eventBlck'.$tres['id'].'">';
            //echo "select * from events where user_id = $uid and timeline=".$tres['id'];exit;
            $user_exe1 = mysql_query("select * from events where user_id = $uid and timeline=".$tres['id']." order by date asc");
            if(mysql_num_rows($user_exe1) > 0) { 
                $i=1;
                $data.='<div class="events-chat-inner">
                <div class="all-cht-blk">
                <div class="event-border">
                <div class="c-dot" style="float:left;position:absolute;left:-4px;top:-4px;"></div>
                <div class="c-dot" style="float:right;position:absolute;right:-4px;top:-4px;"></div>
                </div>
                
                ';
                while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_exe1))
                {

  //Here is the code I just tried to  subtract the date of one event from date of another event.
                   $datecount = count($res['date']);
                   for($j = 0; $j <= $datecount; $j++){


                   $previous_event_date = strtotime($res['date'][j]);
                   $present_event_date = strtotime($res['date'][j+1]);
                   $distance = $previous_event_date - $present_event_date;
                   $distance = floor($distance/(60 * 60 * 24));

                    $case1 = range(0,20);
                    $case2 = range(1,40);
                    if(in_array($distance,$case1))
                    {
                    $distancestyle = 'width:130px';
                     }
                    elseif(in_array($distance,$case2))
                     {
                     $distancestyle = 'width:180px';
                     }
                     else  
                     {
                     $distancestyle = 'width:230px';
                     }
                      



                    if($i%2==0){$bc='#f45e34';}else if($i%3==0){$bc='#fa454a';}else if($i%4==0){$bc='#3cb54b';}else if($i%5==0){$bc='#03aeac';}else{$bc='#9f388b';}
                    if($i%2==0)
                    {

                        $data.='<div class="event-ct-blk" style='\$distancestyle\'>
                        <h3 onclick="getData('.$res['id'].',
                        \''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['name']).'\',
                        \''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['description']).'\',
                        \''.date('m-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).'\');">'.$res['name'].'</h3>
                        <p  onclick="getData('.$res['id'].',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['name']).'\',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['description']).'\',\''.date('m-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).'\');">'.$res['description'].' </p>
                        
                        <div class="pointer">
                        <div class="c-dot"></div>
                        <div class="p-strip-2" style="height:125px;"></div>
                        <div class="q-circle-outer"  onclick="getData('.$res['id'].',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['name']).'\',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['description']).'\',\''.date('m-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).'\');">
                            <div class="q-circle" style="background: '.$bc.';"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-strip" style="height:25px;"></div>
                        <div class="c-dot"></div>
                        </div>

                        

                        <p class="q-date"  onclick="getData('.$res['id'].',
                        \''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['name']).'\',
                        \''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['description']).'\',
                        \''.date('m-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).'\');"> Date: '.date('M-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).' </p>
                        </div>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data.='<div class="event-ct-blk" style='\$distancestyle\'>
                                                
                        <h3 onclick="getData('.$res['id'].',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['name']).'\',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['description']).'\',\''.date('m-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).'\');">'.$res['name'].'</h3>
                        <p  onclick="getData('.$res['id'].',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['name']).'\',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['description']).'\',\''.date('m-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).'\');">'.$res['description'].' </p>
                        <div class="pointer">
                        <div class="c-dot"></div>
                        <div class="p-strip" style="height:25px;"></div>
                        <div class="q-circle-outer"  onclick="getData('.$res['id'].',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['name']).'\',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['description']).'\',\''.date('m-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).'\');">
                        <div class="q-circle" style="background: '.$bc.';"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-strip-2" style="height:125px;"></div>
                        <div class="c-dot"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="q-date"  onclick="getData('.$res['id'].',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['name']).'\',\''.str_replace("'","\'",$res['description']).'\',\''.date('m-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).'\');"> Date: '.date('M-d-Y',strtotime($res['date'])).' </p>
                        </div>';
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                $data.='</div></div>';
                
                }
                else
                {
                    $data.='<div class="event-border" style="width:96%;">
                <div class="c-dot" style="float:left;position:absolute;left:-4px;top:-4px;"></div>
                <div class="c-dot" style="float:right;position:absolute;right:-4px;top:-4px;"></div>
                </div><div style="text-align:center;margin-top:78px;font-size: 18px;"><p>No events added.</p></div>';
                }
            
            
            $data.='</div></div>';  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data='<div class="events-chat" id="timeline1"> <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="addEvent(1)"> Add Event</button><div style="clear:both;margin-bottom:35px;"></div><div id="eventBlck1"> <div class="event-border"  style="width:96%;">
                <div class="c-dot" style="float:left;position:absolute;left:-4px;top:-4px;"></div>
                <div class="c-dot" style="float:right;position:absolute;right:-4px;top:-4px;"></div>
                </div><div style="text-align:center;margin-top:78px;font-size: 18px;"><p>No events added.</p></div></div></div>';
    }
}//end for loop
    
    return $data;


}
```

In this  code I place the code which I marked as the comments and  actually this is the code I have present but  after working on this file events are not showing canyou please see the issue in this code or any errors.

Comment: For one in your for loop you have out of bounds. `$datecount = count($res['date']);for($j = 0; $j <= $datecount; $j++){// $datecount when only 1 element present the loop gets ran twice and out of bounds index gets referenced.`

Comment: Should be `$j <= $datecount - 1`

Comment: And later on theres this line: `$present_event_date = strtotime($res['date'][j+1]);//syntax error since j is not defined, put $j instead` This is also out of bounds in last iteration if you fixed with my code. If you don't need to loop through all of them twice then you could put  `$j <= $datecount -2 ` in the for loop condition. It means the loop wont get ran if there are not at least 2 dates in that array.

Comment: But wait there's more problems in your code. For one how would that $res['date'] include more than one elements since it represents only one row from the database? It's not even an array.

Comment: I won't write the code for you but I can suggest you to fetch the dates into an array indexed by user id _before_ that piece of code you added. Then you can do what you tried.

Comment: Before you begin testing the advices given above, think about using `mysql_*` functions. These functions have been removed in PHP since years. What about turning on the error reporting? This would show you what is wrong. Depending on the PHP version you 're running, this code would die before the sql query is executed.